# SQL: querying specific value in column with XML Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Boy, I've been researching this subject, but I am just not getting it. Sorry if I'm asking a question that has all ready been asked a million times, but its hard to understand when you're a noob like me, and the values in my tables aren't like the others I've seen. So here it goes...

In my SQL Server database, I have a table that has all my listings in it, called *ItemsEbay*.

[image: ItemsEbay]

The main identifier for each individual item has a column ID value called ItemID, so I would like to refer to that as needed.

Within that table is a column named *ItemSpecifics* that contains XML data.
Within the *ItemSpecifics* XML Data, is a node with a `<Name>` of *UPC* text and random value for that node:

[image: XML UPC Node]

What I would like, is a query that would allow me to search all the items in the *ItemsEbay* table that have a specific *UPC* value of my choosing, such as 1000100 or 10U100 for instance.

When I find the match values I'm querying, I would like to be able to replace them all at once with a new value *Does Not Apply*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **do not poste pictures!**

What I've done here is your job: [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

A dummy table with two rows, one contains the searched value, one doesn't

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, ItemSpecifications XML);
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES
 (N'<SelectedValues>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>TestName</Name>
    <Value>Xml1</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>UPC</Name>
    <Value>123</Value><!--The UPC named value = 123 -->
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>')
,(N'<SelectedValues>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>TestName</Name>
    <Value>Xml2</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>UPC</Name>
    <Value>999</Value><!--The UPC named value = 999 -->
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>');
```

--I search for "123" and want to replace it with "SomeOther"

```
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)='123';
DECLARE @ReplaceWith VARCHAR(100)='SomeOther';
```

--The update statement uses `.modify()` for the XML change and `.exist()` to check for the search value below a `<SelectedValue>`, which `<Name>` element has a `text()` of "123":

```
UPDATE @dummyTable SET ItemSpecifications.modify(N'replace value of (/SelectedValues
                                                                     /SelectedValue[(Name/text())[1]="UPC"]
                                                                     /Value/text())[1] 
                                                           with sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")')
WHERE ItemSpecifications.exist(N'/SelectedValues
                                 /SelectedValue[(Name/text())[1]="UPC"]
                                 /Value[text()=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]')=1;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @dummyTable;
```